# shopify private app is not installed giving me this error

Tags: php, shopify

[image]I have cross checked my redirect link is valid oauth even. I have created so many app for shopify private but this one is giving me an

```
The installation link for this app is invalid
The link for installing MeloshluxurygateSlink2 cannot be used. Contact the app developer for more information.
```

could you help me when this error come?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue recently and that was due to a Shopify permission issue. The person who was installing the app was staff with full permissions, covering everything requested in scopes, including app management, but they saw this error. When I tried installing the app (shop owner role), the installation worked without issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).